# Which non-parametric multiple-regression methods are computationally efficient with respect to the number of regressors?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, nonlinear-regression, nonparametric-regression, time-complexity

I did some regression in R with random forests and got some decent results, $1-\sum{|e_i|}/\sum{|y_i-\bar{y}|}=0.692$, but I want to do better than this. Through my research, I have concluded that the category of regression methods I need are non-parametric, because $f(\vec{x})=y$ is nonlinear and I don't know an equation for $f$. Blindly, the next non-parametric method I tried was kernel regression (Nadaraya-Watson, I believe), using the `np` package in R. Unfortunately, this didn't work out, because the algorithm seems to have high complexity for the $n$ of regressors, which are so far **15**. Specifically, kernel regression computed in 142, 621, and 2064 seconds for 2, 3, and 4 variables respectively. Using the most important variables, as identified by random forests, the performance (according to the above metric) was only 0.22, 0.3209, and 0.3208 (actually worsening minutely with the addition of the 4th variable). This is in contrast to random forests, which computed in 26 seconds for 2000 trees and 15 variables, and has continued to reduce error slightly with the addition of variables.

So, i'm wondering which non-parametric regression methods give good results and are also fast for a large $n$ of regressors. If it helps, I can probably afford methods that are relatively slow in the number of data points, which so far is only 1750.

Comment: This is almost always the case for non parametric regression. It is slow, even for fast computers. You might be able to get more speed but using plug in values for the bandwidth

Comment: @Repmat would you count random forests as a non-parametric regression method? If not what category would you put it in? Since random forests are fast, I'm guessing there must be other fast methods for my problem. Or is the issue that fast methods like random forests don't give the best results?

Comment: Np is slow because it uses fullly data driven methods to select parameters. It reruns the regression n times, to find the optimal solution.  This does not happen in RF.

Comment: @Repmat, Interesting. But it doesn't answer the requests for clarification in my above comment. I should also mention that RF performs reasonably with 4 variables at 0.63.

Comment: Ah, no RF isn't really about figuring out a data generating process. So it's really neither